# Power BI : How to use same WorkSpace & Project Name by Multiple Pro User?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

This may be a theoretical question and nothing to do technically.

We are designing multiple page Power BI report with navigation option as like web application.

A couple of Power BI Pro account user want to develop the same Power BI report for the project with multiple pages at same time. How do we can share/sync the changes made between them.

Let's say **User1** creating a report with *first 2 pages* and published/committed changes into "**My Workspace**" with name **BIReport** and **User2** creating 3rd page of the report and committing into the same workspace with the same report name.

Now **User2** want to get first 2 pages of the report which was published by **User1** with all those corresponding measures/Data source and vice versa.

How do I get that? Any idea's/approach are welcome...

Answer (score 1):

You can't work at exact same time in a Power Bi Report. Let's check possibilities:

- Using a git repository with pbix files. You can pull updates before making any change, modify the file and the commit push the file. At the end of the day publish to powerbi.
- Similar to the first, download from Service the .pbix file, modify the report and the publish.
- To reduce the time modifing the file, live connect to the data model. Create report pages and at the end, edit to copy paste in report in order to edit pretty fast the original report and not replace other user changes.
- Create a report for user. If there are too many pages in one report it is not friendly and comfortable, you could live connect to the data model and create at the same time reports with one dataset. Each one modifies one.

Hope this ideas help. There is no safe way to do this now. The first two have the risk that you can't merge conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments... Looking forward to getting comments from other contributors of Power BI too... :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to modify the same report at the same time in Power BI. You can vote for the evolution on the Power BI website :

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/10741866-allow-multiple-users-to-collaborate-on-reports

Though, you can use the One Drive Workspace Option (In the advanced option, while creating the workspace) that will give you the ability to have historical versions of your Power BI reports held in a One Drive folder, directly linked to Power BI, to follow the different updates and to recover a file if something has gone wrong.

Comment: Hi @Vince G, I have tried to use these approach and made it happen.. Is it possible to setup auto-refresh scheduler thru Power BI Gateway for OneDrive files?

Comment: Hello, 

This is a different subject. According to me, the first question is to have a Power BI development like google docs or office online, as you modify a file and it changes the rendering and content for everyone. 

Maybe your question here is different, and putting an "auto schedule". I don't think it is possible for Power BI yet. You can set a Planned Refresh, or doing a Live Query to load data from a DataSource. But having a "deamon" that will update your dataset for a new file in One drive is not possible according to me. 

Regards,